# lightweight cocoa control for displaying rich text

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, user-interface, controls

I am new in mac development and I need a lightweight solution to display rich text:

- text with different font-styles and formatting
- pictures (including animations)
- some controls, like buttons
- picture for text background as an option
- fast text formatting and rendering

I would like to use something like NSTableView with datasource and view delegates, but with the ability to select and copy text with mouse.

I can use WebView for it, but i'm not sure if this solutions will be fast enough and easy to control.
Are there any controls with such a functionality (or close enough) ? 
If there is no such a thing, what should i look to be able to implement it? Can I make a transparent NSTextView over a NSTableView? Is there any way to implement text selecting through several cells in NSTableView (with help of classes like NSTextLayout etc)?

I would be very appreciated for any help and hints.

Answer (score 1):

What you might be missing is `NSAttributedString`, look that up and then look at all the controls for methods that take/return them - just about every control supports rich text, from button labels to scrolling text frames.

Comment: 1. is it possible to set background for text in NSAttributedString?
2. is it possible to place some controls inside nstextview?

Comment: @Sega-Zero - 1. Yes; 2. Harder. Maybe take a look at Apple's TextEdit sample code, you seem to be asking for a pre-packaged full-blown editor and that is one (the code is freely usable).